# Having trouble to play videos in Application using Cordova and Android 4.4

Tags: android, html, video, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I am having trouble to play video using Cordova 3.3 and HTML5 on Android 4.4. I am using JS to play the video using the HTML5 video tag rather than any Cordova plugin, but somehow when I check for canPlayType('application/x-mpegURL') it returns me an empty string instead of returning a "mayBe".

It seems to work fine on Android 4.3 and iOS. But it doesnt work on Android 4.4.

Do I need to add a special permission for Android in cordova config.xml, since Android 4.4 uses Chromium?